# How to use Mathematica to check matrix-vector operations?

Tags: matrix, vector

I would like to use Mathematica to check manual calculation of complex matrix-vector operations. For simple example:

$C_{ij} = A_{ijkl} B_{kl}$

where the matrix $A$ and $B$ might be a complicated function of component $x_i$ such as

$A_{ijkl} = x_i x_j + x_j x_k + x_k x_l + x_l x_i.$

My final goal is to obtain how $C_{ij}$ looks like in a form including $x$. What is the basic strategy to execute such operations that contains Einstein summation convention?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Is the problem that the range for the indices (say $1\leq i\leq n$) is arbitary, or are you happy to do explicit checks for low $n$?

Comment: Have a look at [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct.html)

Comment: @JulesLamers Thanks. It is limited to 3D, so n=3 is fine.

Comment: I know that I am making basic and stupid question, but I'd really like to know the simple/robust strategy to build a Mathematica-code structure in this kind of situation.

Comment: i think you need a more specific example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've never seen Einstein summation convention where you add together terms with different indices (eg. $x_i x_j+x_k x_l$).  Is your question really phrased correctly?

Comment: @evanb Yes, you might be right. I put a random equation that came into my mind, so it may not be correct. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following, which just writes out the summation explicitly, do what you want?

If you first define `A[i_,j_,k_,l_]:=x[i]x[j]+x[j]x[k]+x[k]x[l]+x[l]x[i]` and likewise define $B$, then

```
Table[
  Sum[A[i, j, k, l] B[k, l], {k, 1, 3}, {l, 1, 3}],
  {i, 1, 3}, {j,1, 3}
] // MatrixForm
```

might already do the job, where the output is to be interpreted as the $3\times3$ matrix `C[i,j]`.

Comment: Thank you for wonderful solution! That is the thing I wanted to know. Can I ask you one more question: How should we revise your method when for specific $B$, such as $B=\{\{0, 0.5, 0\}, \{0.5, 0, 0\}, \{0, 0, 0\}\}$?

Comment: You just define `B={{0,1/2,0},{1/2,0,0},{0,0,0}};` . (Use 1/2 instead of .5 to keep things exact.)